# Implementing a non-parallel Spliterator for unknown size?

Tags: java, lambda, parallel-processing, java-8, spliterator

I'm a little confused by all my research. I have custom interface called TabularResultSet (which I've watered down for the sake of example) which traverses through any data set that is tabular in nature. It has a next() method like an iterator and it can be looping through a QueryResultSet, a tabbed-table from a clipboard, a CSV, etc...

However, I'm trying to create a Spliterator that wraps around my TabularResultSet and easily turns it into a stream. I cannot imagine a safe way to parallelize because the TabularResultSet could be traversing a QueryResultSet, and calling next() concurrently could wreak havoc. The only way I imagine parallelization can be done safely is to have the next() called by a single working thread and it passes the data off to a parallel thread to work on it.

So I think parallelization is not an easy option. How do I just get this thing to stream without parallelizing? Here is my work so far...

```
public final class SpliteratorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       TabularResultSet rs = null; /* instantiate an implementation; */

       Stream<TabularResultSet> rsStream = StreamSupport.stream(new TabularSpliterator(rs), false);
    }

    public static interface TabularResultSet {
        public boolean next();

        public List<Object> getData();
    }

    private static final class TabularSpliterator implements Spliterator<TabularResultSet> {

        private final TabularResultSet rs;

        public TabularSpliterator(TabularResultSet rs) {
            this.rs = rs;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super TabularResultSet> action) {
            action.accept(rs);
            return rs.next();
        }

        @Override
        public Spliterator<TabularResultSet> trySplit() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long estimateSize() {
            return Long.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        @Override
        public int characteristics() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably easiest to extend [`Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator.html). If you do this, you need only implement `tryAdvance`. This can be turned into a parallel stream; the parallelism comes from the streams implementation calling `tryAdvance` multiple times, batching up the data it receives, and processing it in different threads.

If `TabularResultSet` is anything like a JDBC `ResultSet`, I don't think you want a `Spliterator<TabularResultSet>` or a `Stream<TabularResultSet>`. Instead it looks like a `TabularResultSet` represents an entire tabular data set, so you probably want each spliterator or stream element to represent one row in that table -- the `List<Object>` that is returned by `getData()`? If so, you'd want something like the following.

```
class TabularSpliterator extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<List<Object>> {
    private final TabularResultSet rs;

    public TabularSpliterator(TabularResultSet rs) {
        super(...);
        this.rs = rs;
    }

    @Override public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super List<Object>> action) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            action.accept(rs.getData());
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can turn an instance of this spliterator into a stream by calling `StreamSupport.stream()`.

Note: in general, a Spliterator instance is not called from multiple threads and need not even be thread-safe. See the [Spliterator class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) at the paragraph beginning "Despite..." for details.

Comment: @ThomasN. Right, the Spliterator itself need not be concerned with being called concurrently. (I've edited in some doc links.) The tryAdvance method may be called multiple times and the results handed off to a different thread, so the results passed to `action.accept()` need to independent of each other. If SingletonTabularSet does that, you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comments due to my followup research indicating what Stuart just confirmed, just as he replied to my comments. To other readers, I was confirming that as long as I extract the data from the `TabularResultSet` safely, I can parallelize the stream. Instead of calling `toList()`, which was a simplified placeholder for this example, I actually will call `toSingletonTabularSet()` which returns an Immutable singleton for one record of a TabularResultSet. If I ever need to parallelize, those SingletonTabularSets can be passed off safely to the threads.

Comment: Okay the more I mused on this the more it made sense. The action.accept() is where the parallelization starts (if any). So as long as the iterated object's state is confined or immutable, it is safe to pass to the action.accept()

Answer (score 1):

You're mostly there. All you have to do now is convert your Spliterator into a Stream.  You can do that using the [StreamSupport.stream(Spliterator, boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-) method.  The boolean parameter is a flag for whether you want to do parallel streaming or not (you would want false, for not parallel)

If your TabularResultSet implemented Iterator, you could use the `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize()` method to convert the Iterator into a Spliterator which basically does what the code you have  above does.

Not sure if it's worth adding characteristics but you might want to consider
`Spliterator.IMMUTABLE| Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL`

good luck

Comment: Was wondering why the collector was receiving null values at the end of the stream. Just realized I needed to do something with the `action` parameter on the `tryNext()` method. I updated above.